# ) is expected, but when I add the ) I also get an error? (React-Native + Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-native

I'm still new to React-Native but I'm using React-Native, TypeScript, and connect it with Firebase. For some reason I get the below error, but as you can see in the other screenshot, the error doesn't exist in VSC and I would have thought my ts lint would have picked it up if this was a problem?

Also, if I do try and add a `)` in line 10 column 33 I get an error?

Exception `expected ")"` shown when I use 'react-native run-ios':

[image: exception]

Here is my code:

[image: code]

And this is the line of the code:

```
loginUser: ({ email, password }: {email: string, password: string}) => void,
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in line 10 ?

Comment: Please paste exception and code as text and not as images.

Comment: @Zac welcome to SO. Please don't paste images with your code, paste text so that developers can easily read and reproduce the error. Only use images only in case that you want to show some behaviour, not to show text or code.

Comment: Line 10 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you remove the image and post the code as an actual code snippet? This allows us to copy it, play with it, edit it and post an efficient answer back to you.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I didn't think about it. Thank you for the info, I'll get the code tomorrow. Line 10 I was hoping to have the login user function take email and password.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring doesn't work in types (which makes sense when you think of it, what does it even mean to destructure in a type?).

```
loginUser: (credentials: {email: string, password: string}) => void,
```